# Mounting HDFS in Ubuntu platform

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Using Ubuntu platform, I am trying to mount HDFS (hadoop 2.2) using HDFS-FUSE but it keeps failing as shown below:

$ **sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20-fuse**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 **hadoop-0.20-fuse : Depends: fuse-utils but it is not installable**
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

$ **sudo apt-get install fuse-utils**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package fuse-utils is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fuse-utils' has no installation candidate

Could you anybody let me know if I need to use any other package to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Even i get the same error. Things have changed it seems, if you want to mount HDFS. try something like this.

http://www.spaggiari.org/index.php/hbase/hadoop-hdfs-fuse-installation#.U5BROPmSwkM